# Проблема с css "трюками" | hover transform элемента

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Решил сделать интересное меню на чистом css. Внешне выглядит хорошо, но вот из-за `transform` съехали "хит поинты" элементов. Так что теперь при наведении в пустую область, срабатывает hover на элемент.

Можно ли переписать стили, чтобы наведение срабатывало только на элементе, а не на том месте, где он должен находится если убрать `transfrom`?

Скорее всего не очень понятно, так что все в примере

```css
body {
  margin-top:100px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu .-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu .-item {
  color: #151515;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.card .-block {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2446cb;
}

.card .-block._left {
  width: 5%;
  transform: rotateZ(30deg) skewX(30deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #2446cb;
}

.card .-block._right {
  min-width: 60%;
  transform: rotateZ(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}

.card:hover .-block {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="-list">
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">1</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Здесь</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">2</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Скоро</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">3</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Будет </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">4</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Меню</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Блок "по коду" прямой, а внешне изменён. Думаю стилями не получится, как-то иначе, например канвасом.

Comment: У вас ховер висит на `card`, а у `card` никакого transform нет, вот и причина. Правда, как по-умному исправить, пока не придумалось

Comment: @adreymal Не заметил про `.card`, то что он не трансформируется, а вот `-block` меняется. Попробую решить через js, отслеживая наведение на `-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось в js

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card .-block').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.parentNode.classList.add('_hover');
  });

  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.parentNode.classList.remove('_hover');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu .-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu .-item {
  color: #151515;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.card .-block {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2446cb;
}

.card .-block._left {
  width: 5%;
  transform: rotateZ(30deg) skewX(30deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #2446cb;
}

.card .-block._right {
  min-width: 60%;
  transform: rotateZ(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}

.card._hover .-block {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="-list">
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">1</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Здесь</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">2</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Скоро</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">3</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Будет </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="-block _left">4</div>
        <div class="-block _right">Меню</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```